# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-options-api

I am creating a searching input using Vue and and I made a method to check if each item should be visible or not and compare the current user input with the data of the item, and return true or false.
The problem I have with the console, it shows me an Error related to "toLowerCase".
please some help and advice.
Thanks in advance.

```
<div
  v-for="item in itemList"
  :key="item.name"
  class="dropdown-item"
  v-show="itemVisible(item)"
 />

export default {
  name: "Demo",
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      itemList: [],
      selectedItem: {},
    };
  },
itemVisible(item) {
  let currentName = item.name.toLowerCase();
  let currentInput = this.inputValue.toLowerCase();
  return currentName.includes(currentInput);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `itemVisible(item)` function should have been put inside of the `methods` object but event then it probably would not work as you expected because it would only get executed once on the initial render.

You probably want to `watch` the `inputValue` parameter and then go and execute the `itemVisible()` method on every item of `selectedItems` and save the data about visibility directly to the item or in a parallel data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
<template>
    <ul v-for="(item, idx) in itemList" :key="`key-${idx}`">
        <li class="dropdown-item" v-show="itemVisible(item)">
            {{ item.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "Demo",

    data() {
        return {
            inputValue: "i",
            itemList: [
                { name: 'hi' },
                { name: 'by' },
            ],
            selectedItem: {},
        };
    },

    methods() {
        itemVisible(item) {
            let currentName  = item.name.toLowerCase();
            let currentInput = this.inputValue.toLowerCase();
            return currentName.includes(currentInput);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

If you don't want ul/li you can swap ul with template and li with div

```
<template ...loop... > <div class="..."> {{ item.name }} </div> </template>
```